# Alt actions not triggering alt store methods when dispatched (Flux)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flux, datastore, alt.js

I've recently started rewriting a flux & react app using alt.js which allows me easily bootstrap the application with data when rendering from the server.

Everything else works great apart from the fact that I cannot get my store methods to fire when an action has been dispatched client side.

The action `updateCurrentPostType` is being called from an `onClick` event in one of my react components. After running some tests I can confirm that both my Action and callback are being fired but the store doesn't seem to be picking anything up.

I've tried using bindListeners & bindAction methods in my stores constructor but still no result.

I know it's not really much of a question but I'm hoping somebody with a bit more experience using alt will be able to see if I am missing anything vital out.

**"alt": "^0.14.5"**

Here is my code. Thanks for your time.

**PostTypeLink.jsx** (React component, Action called in loadPostType method)

```
"use strict";

var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var PostTypeActions = require('../../../actions/postTypeActions');

var PostTypeLink = React.createClass({

    contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.func
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return this.props.postType;
    },

    loadPostType: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = this;
        var postTypeName = this.props.postType.info.posttype_name;

        PostTypeActions.updateCurrentPostType(postTypeName, function() {

            self.context.router.transitionTo('/admin/content/'+postTypeName);
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        var postTypeName = this.props.postType.info.posttype_name;

        return (
            <li key={this.props.key}>
                <a href="#" onClick={this.loadPostType}>
                    <i className="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i> {_.startCase(postTypeName)}
                </a>
            </li>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = PostTypeLink;
```

**PostTypeActions.js**

```
"use strict";

var alt = require('../alt');
var request = require('superagent');

class PostTypeActions {

    loadAllPostTypes(cb) {
        var self = this;

        request
        .get('/api/v1/posttypes')
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Request Failed: '+err);
            } else {
                var response = JSON.parse(res.text);

                self.actions.updatePostTypes(response);

                if (cb) {
                    cb();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    updatePostTypes(postTypes){
        this.dispatch(postTypes);
    }

    updateCurrentPostType(postTypeName, cb){
        console.log('updating current post type');
        this.dispatch(postTypeName);

        if (cb) {
            cb();
        }
    }
}

module.exports = alt.createActions(PostTypeActions);
```

**PostTypeStore.js**

```
"use strict";

var alt = require('../alt');
var PostTypeActions = require('../actions/PostTypeActions');

class PostTypeStore {

    constructor() {
        var self = this;

        this.bindListeners({
            updatePostTypes: PostTypeActions.updatePostTypes,
            updateCurrentPostType: PostTypeActions.updateCurrentPostType
        });

        this.on('init', function() {
            self.postTypes = [];
            self.currentPostType = null;
        });
    }

    updatePostTypes(postTypes) {
        this.postTypes = postTypes;
        this.emitChange();
    }

    updateCurrentPostType(postTypeName) {
        var self = this,
            _postTypes = this.postTypes;

        for (var i = 0; i < _postTypes.length; i++) {
            if ( _postTypes[i].info.posttype_name == postTypeName ) {
                console.log(_postTypes[i]);
                self.currentPostType = _postTypes[i];
                self.emitChange();
            }
        }
        console.log('THIS METHOD WONT FIRE!!!!');
        console.log(self.currentPostType);
    }
}

module.exports = alt.createStore(PostTypeStore, 'PostTypeStore');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually require the Store somewhere for it to be compiled into the code and for it to start listening to the actions. Just creating a store isn't enough. Simple requiring it PostTypeLink.jsx above should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. Will update my code when I get a chance and let you know if it works.